# mod_rewrite does not rewrite jsp files

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've set up everything and mod_rewrite works properly on HTML files but not on jsp files.

I'm getting the following message in my rewrite log:

(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.jsp applying pattern '^/([\w\d]*).jsp$' to uri '/index.jsp'
(2) rewrite '/index.jsp' -> '/sb/jsp/index.jsp'
(2) forcing '/sb/jsp/index.jsp' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler

I've set up mod_jk and I can access /sb/jsp/index.jsp with no issue. I would like to have users access /index.jsp and then be rewritten to /sb/jsp/index.jsp.

My rewrite rule (notice I use the PT flag to force mod_rewrite to forward to mod_jk):

RewriteRule ^/([\w\d]*).jsp$ /sb/jsp/$1.jsp [PT] [NC] [QSA] [L]

Anyone has any idea what's going on? seems like the request is being forwarded but never gets to mod_jk.

Another thing I just noticed. If I take the PT flag out I get a different message in the log:
 (1) go-ahead with /sb/jsp/index.jsp [OK]
And the /index.jsp instead of /sb/jsp/index.jsp
So seems like apache is forwarding to tomcat but not the rewritten URL...

Thanks!

Comment: RewriteRule ^/([\w\d]*).jsp$ /sb/jsp/$1.jsp [PT,NC,QSA,L]

All my rewriter rules have the Flags in a single set of brackets for what it is worth..I had trouble with complex rules when I separated the flags.

Comment: Thanks. Changed this to: RewriteRule ^/([\w\d]*)\.jsp$ /sb/jsp/$1.jsp [PT,NC,QSA,L]

Comment: but still the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

^/([\w\d]*).jsp$ /sb/jsp/$1.jsp

Something does not look correct above.

Below is a rule out of my running config.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://agent.hepmepls.com:8443$1 [R,NE,QSA,P,L]
```

This rule will take everything after the .* and wrap it around the URL I want....like this

```
http://agent.hepmepls.com/megavil?argue/junk.html
becomes
http://agent.hepmepls.com:8443/megavil?argue/junk.html
```

But I feel like the $ and $1 are tripping you up...I could be completely wrong..but if you fire something though your rule would it not do the following..

```
http://hepmepls.com/something.jsp?l8trarguments==
becomes
http://hepmepls.com/?l8trarguments==.jsp
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The problem here is that somehow mod_rewrite isn't forwarding rewritten request to mod_jk but rather the regular initial URL. If I replace the rewrite rule with a simple one, with no $ replacements I get the same problem...

Comment: I tried to recreate your situation...I cannot fix it either..do let us know if you come up with a solution.